# Одновременная фильтрация значений "NA" и заданного значения в одном столбце R

Tags: r

Необходимо в одном столбце Item одновременно сделать фильтрацию по определенному продукту и по значениям "NA", чтобы по итогу получилось:

Item
NA
Phone
NA
NA
NA

Приведенный ниже код результатов не даёт:

```
filter_table <- filter(.data = restore_demand, is.na(Item) & Item == "Phone")
```

Comment: `|` вместо `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Завершенный пример по комментариям `Artem Klevtsov`

```
# создаем тестовый набор данных
df.tst  <- data.frame(Item = as.character(c(NA, "Phone", "Model1", "Model1", "Model2", NA, NA, "Phone", "Phone", "Model2", "Model3", "Model2", NA, NA, "Phone")))

    Результат:

    > df.tst
    Item
    1    <NA>
    2   Phone
    3  Model1
    4  Model1
    5  Model2
    6    <NA>
    7    <NA>
    8   Phone
    9   Phone
    10 Model2
    11 Model3
    12 Model2
    13   <NA>
    14   <NA>
    15  Phone

# подключаем пакет
library(dplyr)

# фильтруем данные
df.rslt  <- filter(df.tst, is.na(Item) == TRUE | Item=="Phone")

    > df.rslt
    Item
    1  <NA>
    2 Phone
    3  <NA>
    4  <NA>
    5 Phone
    6 Phone
    7  <NA>
    8  <NA>
    9 Phone
```